# CDI compilation failure - annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I have a Weld qualifier annotation declared like this:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({Field, Method, Constructor})
public @interface AccountResponse {
}
```

My bean interface is this:

```
@Stateless
public interface Responder {
    /* Declares stuff */
}
```

The qualified implementation is this:

```
@AccountResponse
public class AccountResponseResponder implements Responder {
    /* Does stuff */
}
```

The Maven compiler says (on AccountResponseResponder.java):

```
annotation type not applicable to this type of declaration
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but what it is escapes me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Target({Field, Method, Constructor})` 
Means you can only apply this annotation to given parts of your code. In order to enable class annotation you would have to add `Type` to the `@Target`